# Error 10500 directed at alias declaration

Tags: compiler-errors, syntax-error, vhdl, hdl

The code I'm having trouble with spits a control word into several pieces so they can be used by their respective circuits.

When I attempt to compile this code, I get two 10500 errors for each alias line:
"Near text "alias"; expecting "end", or "(" or an identifier, or a concurrent statement"
"Near text "is"; expecting ";", or "generic".

I tried adding an "end;" and "end alias" after the alias declarations, but it still returned the same errors.

I also attempted adding "signal" in various parts of the declaration, but this also still resulted in the same error.

Origially I had converted the std_logic_vector to bit_vector before ths block, and the alias output were bit types instead of std_logic, but I changed it to std_logic thinking the type conversion was the problem.

```
--Splits control word into specific sections.
    Architecture split of t11214 is
            Begin
                Alias enable_input: std_logic is instruction(1);
                Alias enable_output: std_logic is instruction(2);
                Alias select_accumulator: std_logic is instruction(3);
                Alias select_operand: std_logic_vector(1 to 2) is instruction(4 to 5);
                Alias select_prcmp: std_logic_vector(1 to 2) is instruction(6 to 7);
                Alias select_prenot: std_logic_vector(1 to 2) is instruction(8 to 9);
                Alias select_function: std_logic_vector(1 to 2) is instruction(10 to 11);
                Alias select_rng: std_logic is instruction(12);
                Alias shift: std_logic_vector(1 to 4) is instruction(13 to 16);
    End architecture split;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Alias` is part of the declarations, so it must be **before** the `Begin`, thus like:

```
Architecture split of t11214 is
  ...
  Alias enable_input: std_logic is instruction(1);
  ...
Begin
  ...
End architecture split;
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been messing around with this code for hours, can't believe the mistake was so simple.